# how do I button clicked before outputting the results?

Tags: javascript

So there're 2 radio items and I want the user to choose which one to execute, after the user chooses one of them, he/she will click on the button "Draw!" and will output the result from one of the function of the radio item they chose. But I can't figure out how to call either function and wait until the user clicks on the "Draw!" button to actually calls the function.

I have in my HTML:

```
<p>
Do you want to <input type="radio" name="draw" id="draw" value="drawTriangle">Draw Triangle
or
<input type="radio" name="draw" id="draw" value="drawZigZag">Draw ZigZag<br>
<input type="button" value="Draw!" onclick="drawEither()">
</p>

<pre id="outputTriangle">
</pre>

<pre id="outputZigZag">
</pre>
```

and Javascript:

```
function makeZigZag () {
var sizeTextField = document.getElementById('sizeTextField')
//block of codes
drawButton.onclick = function () {
    outputTri.innerHTML = makeTriangle(sizeTextField.value);
};

}

function makeTriangle () {
var sizeTextField = document.getElementById('sizeTextField')
//block of codes
drawButton.onclick = function () {
    outputZZ.innerHTML = makeTriangle(sizeTextField.value);
};
}

function drawEither () {
outputTri = document.getElementById('outputTriangle');
outputZZ = document.getElementById('outputZigZag');
}
```

Comment: Kenenth, please format your code properly and bring your DOM input field names in sync with your JavaScript code. BTW: Where does your `drawButton` come from?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be a loop to check which radio button is selected. Something like:

```
function drawEither () {
  if (document.getElementById('drawTriangle').checked) {
    do stuff for radio 1
  } else {
    do stuff for radio 2
  }
}
```

By the way, you have duplicate IDs in your example HTML. IDs must be unique. I've used a suggested ID in my example.

Comment: Why would you need a loop. We got events for that in the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure how a click event on the radio buttons can be leveraged for a click on the button. Feel free to post an alternative answer.

Comment: I was commenting the first version of your answer. Now its fine, now your `drawEither()` is an event handler for onclick() on the Draw button. All good. :-)